# Поиск по одному полю Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

Я новичек в Hibernate.

Есть `UserRepository` и `RestController`.

Хочу сделать поиск по одному из полей юзера: Имя, фамилия, пол.

Если с получением всех юзеров, поиск по id все понятно. Но как сделать выборку только по одному полю?

```
public interface UserRepository {
    UserEntity save(UserEntity car);
    void update(UserEntity user);
    List<UserEntity> getAll();
    List<UserEntity> getAllByFirstName();
    List<UserEntity> getAllByLastName();
    List<UserEntity> getAllByGender();
    UserEntity getById(Long id);
    void remove(Long id);
}

@Repository
@Transactional()
public class UserRepositoryImpl  implements UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserEntity save(UserEntity user) {
        if(user.getId() != null){
            return entityManager.merge(user);
        } else {
            entityManager.persist(user);
            return user;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(UserEntity user) {

    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAll() {
        CriteriaQuery<UserEntity> criteria = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(UserEntity.class);
        criteria.select(criteria.from(UserEntity.class));
//        criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get( Person_.name ), "John Doe" ) );

        return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAllByFirstName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAllByLastName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAllByGender() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity getById(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(UserEntity.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Long id) {
        UserEntity user = getById(id);
        if(user != null) {
            entityManager.remove(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public interface UserService {
    UserEntity save(UserEntity userEntityy);
    List<UserEntity> getAll();
    UserEntity getById(long id);
    void remove(long id);
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserEntity save(UserEntity userEntityy) {
        return userRepository.save(userEntityy);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAll() {
        return userRepository.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity getById(long id) {
        return userRepository.getById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(long id) {
        userRepository.remove(id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Что мешает использовать hql?

Comment: @bench_doos пример можно?

Comment: К примеру получение пользователя по username

`@Override
    @Transactional
    public UsersEntity getUserByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = session.createQuery("from UsersEntity where username = :username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);

        final UsersEntity entity = (UsersEntity) query.uniqueResult();
        log.debug("User found by username " + username + ": " + entity);
        return entity;
    }`

правда немного не понятно, что хочешь получить в
`List<UserEntity> getAllByFirstName();` и тд

Comment: Зачем запросы? У вас же хибер... Если хотите запросы - выкидывайте хибер. Если хотите хибер, выкидывайте запросы. Есть DetachedCriteria, есть Restrictions.

Comment: @test123 пример можно?

Comment: Для получения сессии можете посмотреть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148231/how-can-i-get-the-session-object-if-i-have-the-entitymanager Вот пример критерия, который вы хотите: https://pastebin.com/BkBPWPsp Эта критерия выберет записи где имя эквивалентно name. (примерно: Select ... from ? where name = ?)

Comment: Кстати, то как вы пишите, больше напоминает EntityFramework. Вам не кажется, что проще разделить DAO, которые создают запросы/критерии (и только создают), сервис DAO, который выполняет критерии и механизмы save/remove/update?

Comment: @test123 выложил сервис в шапке. так? я просто не понимаю смысла. Если в сервисе и в репозитории будет одно и тоже и что бы добавить критерий это нужно делать как в репозитории так и в сервисе. просветите?

Comment: Вы не поняли суть сервиса... Первое - каждая сущность (тот же UserEntity), должны иметь базовый класс, чтобы организовать более менее простой код (без заумных генериков) Пример функций внутри сервиса DAO https://pastebin.com/p7J9H2wc Сама DAO для конкретных манипуляций будет своя, а не как у вас. Вы пытаетесь сделать всё-в-одном, свалку из работы с БД. Далее, примером DAO, например, работающей с вашей сущностью  UserEntity можно представить так: https://pastebin.com/B0ff1LJx

Comment: Если вы заметили, теперь смотря на DAO для работы с пользователем, вам не мешает ничего лишнего. Не нужно думать о сессиях, не нужно писать какие то запросы и что то там обрабатывать, основные функции реализует за вас сервис, который обязан выпонить select/remove/update/insert. А написать "запрос" можно просто собрав критерию. Ну, про extends IServiceDAO я конечно соврал, тут нужно поднять класс, и всё это дело реализовать. Как именно - ваше дело, важно чтобы об этом не думал тот кто пишет DaoImpls

Comment: @test123 я так понимаю что у интерфейса IServiceDAO есть IServiceDAOImpl версия и от неё нужно наследоваться, а не от интерфейса. Можно полный пример? пожалуйста. для понимания.

Comment: Не "нужно наследоваться", а "можно". Это дело вкуса. Суть в том, что наследуясь - вы клонируете/копируете сервис. Можно не копировать, а ссылаться на один и тот же сервис из кучи различных DAO. Вот более менее полный пример, каким он может быть, и каким его вижу я. https://pastebin.com/ymM0yhgB Повторюсь, это не значит что так должно быть. + Если уж вы изучаете java, есть некие соглашения, на вроде того, что у интерфейсов желательно делать префикс I в имени.

Comment: @test123 подскажите гайды или ресурс где Вы это берете пожалуйста

Comment: о_О книги и документация

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/2ibyTzEg37xwzP в папочке java, советую глянуть Clean Code, если нужны основы, Thinking in Java довольно не плоха

Comment: Помощь непосредственно по хиберу - есть в документациях к хиберу. http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.2/